# Lying in plain sight

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or phrase, that accurately describes this: When someone tells you about something, or talks about something off the cuff and describes it as repulsive, or derogatory as a way of ensuring that you don't think they have anything to do with the said topic. Say, someone that hasn't come out, and constantly describes homosexuality as disgusting, or someone who watches tv soaps but constantly moans about how much they despise tv soaps and think people that watch them is hopeless, or your partner describes something they find intolerable yet are themselves avid instigators of such acts? I guess what I'm asking is what is the word of openly admitting guilt to mask involvement?

Comment: Not a single word, but [the lady doth protest too much, methinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lady_doth_protest_too_much,_methinks) (from *Hamlet*) appears relevant.

Comment: I was with you until your last sentence. They aren’t openly admitting guilt.  They are denying their own guilt by attacking others who are guilty.

Answer (score 1):

***reaction formation***

> ...is *a type of defense mechanism in which a person acts in the exact opposite manner to his own disturbing or socially unacceptable thoughts or emotions.* This behavior is often unconscious and appears exaggerated, perhaps in an effort to overcompensate for the embarrassment, guilt or repulsion the person feels regarding his private thoughts.

-[PsychCentral](https://psychcentral.com/encyclopedia/reaction-formation/)

Some colorful examples...

> Let's say that you secretly harbor lustful feelings toward someone you should probably stay away from. *You don't want to admit to these feelings, so you instead express the very opposite of those feelings.* This object of your lust now becomes the object of your bitter hatred. This defense mechanism could be subtitled the "lady doth protest too much," that wonderful quote from Hamlet. A less highbrow example is "Church Lady," the old Dana Carvey character from Saturday Night Live. Her secret obsession with pornography became reversed into her extreme scorn for all things sexual. In short, reaction formation means expressing the opposite of your inner feelings in your outward behavior.

-[Psychology today online](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/fulfillment-any-age/201110/the-essential-guide-defense-mechanisms)

You might notice that the same phrase offered by mod Andrew Leach is included in the passage.

[emphasis mine in both passages]

Comment: This seems like a good fit, but how central to this notion is the bit about one’s “disturbing or socially unacceptable thoughts or emotions”? If that’s central, then I don’t think this would necessarily be a good fit after all, because the two examples mentioned in the question (being gay and watching soap operas) are neither disturbing nor socially unacceptable. Obviously, they’re disturbing _to the person who’s denying them_, but not to (most of) society at large; the description quoted is a bit vague, so I can’t really tell whether it fits here or not.

Comment: ...should probably be closed, as it is a SWR tag and no cloze sentence to illustrate the usage. @JanusBahsJacquet

Answer (score 0):

Following from your question, the words "**conspicuous**" and "**obvious**" seem suitable for *"lying in plain sight"*. There is also "**apparent**" which might better address the non-physical concepts that have been offered for example.

Following from your description, perhaps they do "**protest too much**". *The Shakespearean phrase/idiom implies that too much protest implies underlying guilt*. The title question was asked with a single-word-request tag, but the question description asked for a word or phrase. I hope this phrase suits the situation.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conspicuous

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obvious

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/apparent

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/protest+too+much